# hourly heatmap from multi years timeseries python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, subplot

I need to create a hourly mean multi plot heatmap of Temperature as in:

[image]

for sevel years. The data to plot are read from excel sheet. The excel sheet is formated as `"year"`, `"month"`, `"day"`, `"hour"`, `"Temp"`.

I created a mounthly mean heatmap using seaborn library, using this code :

```
df = pd.read_excel('D:\\Users\\CO2_heatmap.xlsx')
co2=df.pivot_table(index="month",columns="year",values='CO2',aggfunc="mean")
ax = sns.heatmap(co2,cmap='bwr',vmin=370,vmax=430, cbar_kws={'label': '$\mathregular{CO_2}$ [ppm]', 'orientation': 'vertical'})
```

Obtaining this graph:

[image]

How can I generate a

```
co2=df.pivot_table(index="hour",columns="day",values='CO2',aggfunc="mean")
```

for each month and for each year?

Answer (score 2):

The seaborn heat map did not allow me to draw multiple graphs of different axes. I created a graph by SNSing that one graph with multiple graphs. It was not customizable like the reference graph. Sorry we are not able to help you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

date_rng  = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2019-12-31',freq='1H')
temp = np.random.randint(-30.0, 40.0,(17497,))
df = pd.DataFrame({'CO2':temp},index=pd.to_datetime(date_rng))
df.insert(1, 'year', df.index.year)
df.insert(2, 'month', df.index.month)
df.insert(3, 'day', df.index.day)
df.insert(4, 'hour', df.index.hour)
df = df.copy()
yyyy = df['year'].unique()
month = df['month'].unique()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10), nrows=2, ncols=12)

for m, ax in zip(range(1,25), axes.flat):
    if m <= 12:
        y = yyyy[0]
        df1 = df[(df['year'] == y) & (df['month'] == m)]
    else:
        y = yyyy[1]
        m -= 12
        df1 = df[(df['year'] == y) & (df['month'] == m)]
    df1 = df1.pivot_table(index="hour",columns="day",values='CO2',aggfunc="mean")
    plt.figure(m)
    sns.heatmap(df1, cmap='RdBu', cbar=False, ax=ax)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This might help- /hourly-heatmap-graph-using-python-s-ggplot2-implementation-plotnine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64410412/hourly-heatmap-graph-using-python-s-ggplot2-implementation-plotnine)

There's also a guide to producing this exact plot (for two years of data) on the

[Python graph gallery-heatmap-for-timeseries-matplotlib](https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/heatmap-for-timeseries-matplotlib)

I'm afraid I don't know any Python, so didn't want to copy/paste in case I missed anything.  I did, however, create the original plot in R :) The main trick was to use facet_grid to split the data by year and month, and reverse the y axis labels.

It looks like

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 12, figsize=(14, 10), sharey=True)

for i, year in enumerate([2004, 2005]):
    for j, month in enumerate(range(1, 13)):
        single_plot(data, month, year, axes[i, j])
```

does the work of splitting by year and month.
I hope this helps you get further forward