# Hourly heatmap graph using Python’s ggplot2 implementation ‘plotnine’?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, plotnine

I am trying to create an hourly heatmap from within Python. A code example of this graph made in R is available here: [r-graph-gallery.com/283-the-hourly-heatmap.html](http://r-graph-gallery.com/283-the-hourly-heatmap.html). It relies on ggplot2.

[image: hourly heatmap]

There also is a Python implementation of ggplot2 called plotnine: [github.com/has2k1/plotnine](http://github.com/has2k1/plotnine)

Anybody able to “translate” from R to Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple recreation in `plotnine` [docs](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) using a small dataset. Most of the `geom_*` elements from `ggplot2` are implemented (mostly with underscores replacing dots in names). If you want to maintain the `R` flavor of directly calling the `geom_*` functions, you can just change the first line to `from plotnine import *`.

```
import plotnine as p9
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#%% Build dataset
df = pd.DataFrame({'Month':pd.Categorical(['Jan','Feb','Mar']*2*3*4,
                                          categories=['Jan','Feb','Mar']),
                   'Year':([2004]*3+[2005]*3)*3*4,
                   'Hour Commencing':([1]*3*2+[2]*3*2+[3]*3*2)*4,
                   'Day':[j for i in range(1,5) for j in [i]*3*2*3]})
# Add the hourly temp as random values
df['Hourly Temps'] = np.random.randint(-10,40,size=df.shape[0])


#%% Build the plot
g = (p9.ggplot(df,p9.aes(x='Day',y='Hour Commencing',fill='Hourly Temps'))
     + p9.geom_tile(color='white',size=.1)
     + p9.facet_grid('Year~Month')
     + p9.labs(title='Hourly Temps - Station T0001')
     + p9.scale_fill_cmap('plasma')
     + p9.theme(legend_position = 'bottom',
               plot_title = p9.element_text(size=14),
               axis_text_y = p9.element_text(size=6)))
print(g)
```

[image: Sample Plot]

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm. I am still struggling how to set the xtics and ytics. In the R script this is done using: ‘p <-p + scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse", breaks = unique(df$hour))
p <-p + scale_x_continuous(breaks =c(1,10,20,31))’

Comment: You can set them the same way in plotnine. You just have to replace `unique(df$hour)` with `df['Hour Commencing'].unique()` and use a python list (`[1,10,20,31]`) instead of the R vector.